# avoid inline functions for performance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I heard inline functions like this is bad:

```
onPress={() => handleSubmit()}
```

you should use this instead:

```
onPress={handleSubmit}
```

But what I make if I have an argument like this:

```
onPress={(val) => handleSubmit(val)}
```

so then its not working without arrow

So is there another performant way ?

Comment: *so then its not working without arrow* - this is incorrect. It would work exactly the same. Try it out

Comment: Unless `handleSubmit` uses `this` internally (which is a different problem) then `handleSubmit` and `(val) => handleSubmit(val)` are equivalent (with the latter being a little inefficient because it has to create an extra function on each render).

Comment: It will work without the arrow function. simply use onPress={handleSubmit} and access the param in function prop.

Comment: I would be willing to bet that performance issues due to inline arrow functions are an observable issue in one in 10000 projects (to make up numbers). The arrow function is completely unnecessary, but performance is not going to be a real problem, only a theoretical one.